# How to handle a jQuery AJAX response of a web page

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery function that passes some parameters (x and y) of the mouse location and then returns some value based on my parameters. I originally was having the page pass back data in the request itself and getting it like this:

```
request["somevariable"]
```

Now I am trying to do an AJAX jQuery call. Here is my jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".myControl").click(function (e) {
        var posX = $(this).position().left;
        var posY = $(this).position().top;
        $.post("GetFeatureData.aspx", {
            x: posX,
            y: posY
        },
        function (data, status) {
            alert("Data: " + posX + "\n" + posY + "\n" + "\n" + data + "\n" + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
```

How do I get information from parameters in the request itself. `GetFeatureData.aspx` just passes back some information back to the calling page as parameters. Example: `mypage.aspx?id=15`.
How can I retrieve `id` assuming of course the original page calling the jQuery is `mypage.aspx`

Comment: Are you just looking for something like `Request.QueryString` in WebForms?

Comment: yes basically that's what I am doing. I need to call it from javascript or jquery

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  You have JavaScript code which calls a server-side resource.  On the server, you get the values from the query string collection.  On the client, you *supplied* the values so you already have them.  Can you clarify exactly what the problem is here?

Comment: Oh yeah sure sorry about that. I am trying to pass values to the server using Ajax via jquery. The server side page is doing a process and sending back a response to the user. Using webforms this works fine by getting the request.querystring. I now want to use ajax so I can avoid the ugly posting back refresh.

Comment: example: pagea.aspx has a jquery call to pageb,aspx. Pageb.aspx does some stuff and calls pagea.aspx?parameters=something.

Comment: Well, you're already using AJAX.  That's what the `$.post()` function does.  The anonymous function you pass in as an argument to `$.post()` is how you handle the response.

Comment: how can I get back any request parameters... is it data.XXXX

Comment: What do you mean by "get back request parameters"?  Anything that was in the request you already have.  Anything that's in the response is in the `data` object.  For example, if you respond with JSON data then the `data` object will contain that data.  I really think you've tried to take your design in a fundamentally incorrect direction and that direction is causing some confusion around whatever it is you're asking.

Comment: Do I need to create a json response and send that back?

Comment: AJAX requests are most commonly responded to with JSON data, yes.  It's not essential, but it's generally the easiest approach.

Comment: Ok. I hadn't ever used jquery and my ajax has always been done using the simple `ScriptManager` and `UpdatePanel`